Continuous even function from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{S}^1$
Given a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{S^1}$ it holds that $f(x) = f(-x)$. Is the function $f$ always a constant function?
I would like to characterize this so that I can show that the induced homomorphism in the 1-homology group, that is $f_*\colon H_1(\mathbb{S}^1) \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)$, maps everything to 0.

What about $f(e^{i \phi}) = e^{2 i \phi}$ (which is $z \mapsto z^2$ if you identify $\cal S^1$ with the unit circle in the complex plane) ?

@MartinR I think you should turn this into an answer. :)

Yeah, this is really far away from being true.  Maybe there is another way to deduce what you need.

@BenSteffan: This looks like an XY-problem to me (“... so that I can show that ...”) and homology groups are not my area of expertise. Perhaps someone with more knowledge in that area can post an answer to the real problem.

An even function $f\colon S^1 \to S^1$ need not be constant, and $f_*\colon H_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)$ need not be zero either.
For a counterexample to both, the map $f\colon S^1 \to S^1$, $z \mapsto z^2$ Martin R provided in the comments is even since $z^2 = (-z)^2$ for all $z \in S^1$ (here we consider $S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$), and it induces multiplication by 2 on $\pi_1 S^1$, so letting $h\colon \pi_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)$ be the Hurewicz homomorphism, the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \pi_1(S^1) @>\pi_1(f)> \cdot 2> \pi_1(S^1) \\
    @VhV\cong V @V\cong VhV \\
    H_1(S^1) @>>H_1(f)> H_1(S^1)
\end{CD}
commutes by naturality of $h$, whence $H_1(f)$ is multiplication by 2 as well and in particular nonzero.
